# coinbase FIX api

Tags: fix-protocol, coinbase-api

I am trying to implement Coinbase's FIX api.   I have managed to successful send the Logon Message (A) but I can't mange to successfully send the place order message (D).   When I try to place an order I get back an error "CompID problem".  I send fix field 49={my api key} and the fix field 56=Coinbase.

Comment: Sounds like you got the CompIDs wrong. But maybe it's best if you asked them directly about it. They might see the problem in their logs.

Comment: Looking at https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#connectivity you seem to do it correctly, maybe they don't gave you access yet? As I said, best is to ask them.